# Ansible replace single quotes regexp

Tags: ansible

I have the following attempt in ansible:

```yaml
---
- name: Replace string nulls with php nulls in config
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ app_root_path }}/config/autoload.local.php"
    regexp: "\'''null\'''"
    replace: 'null'
    backup: yes
```

To implement this regex:

[image: regex101]

in order to change:

```php
'host'     => 'null',
'user'     => 'null',
'password' => 'null',
```

to:

```php
'host'     => null,
'user'     => null,
'password' => null,
```

I've tried:

- ```yaml
  regexp: "\''null\''"
  ```
- ```yaml
  regexp: "\'null\'"
  ```
- ```yaml
  regexp: "''null''"
  ```

None of these, nor anything else I've found so far, has worked.

What is the correct way of implementing this in the confines of YAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to double the backslashes, not the quotes.

> In YAML, text scalars can be surrounded by quotes enabling escape sequences such as `\n` to represent a new line, `\t` to represent a tab, and `\\` to represent the backslash.

<sup>*Source: https://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-08-01.html#sec-concept*</sup>

The task:

```yaml
- name: Replace string nulls with php nulls in config
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ app_root_path }}/config/autoload.local.php"
    regexp: "\\'null\\'"
    replace: 'null'
    backup: yes
```

would give:

```php
'host'     => null,
'user'     => null,
'password' => null,
```

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong but I've tried this and although it runs it doesn't make any changes to the file, which makes me think it didn't locate the `'null'`s?

Comment: Run your playbook with `-vvvv` and show us the full output of it, then?

Comment: I messed up import_task with include_task, it was validating schema but not running. Double backslash single quote works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the lines to below -

```
regexp: "\'null\'"
replace: "null"
```

Also, you need to specify the hosts you would be going to run the playbook on. The complete playbook should look something like this -

```
- hosts: <hostname/groupname/all>
  
  tasks:

        - name: Replace string nulls with php nulls in config
          ansible.builtin.replace:

            path: "{{ app_root_path }}/config/autoload.local.php"
            regexp: "\'null\'"
            replace: "null"
            backup: yes
```

Please double check the code indentation as well :)

Comment: Ansible gives a YAML syntax error for this attempt.

Comment: @bcmcfc... Just updated my response with your complete playbook

Comment: Same result... the task in the question is not the full playbook but just the relevant excerpt.

Comment: @bcmcfc.... Well that's strange... tried it across different Ansible and RHEL versions... It has worked for me... You mentioned that this is not the complete playbook... so you might as well need to check the other plays as well. Ansible sometimes throws errors that are not at all on the same line but somewhere else (Like an indentation error sometimes).

Comment: It needed the double backslash single quote